# Is it haram if I make game that is about god?

Tags: halal-haram

Hello I'm a game designer and I'm worry about my work right now. If I designed game that story is about god (like god of war) I'm afraid that maybe it is haram? if I make it for fun and I don't think  that charecter is my god.

So if someone love my game and he or she praise my charecter game that it is a god in my game(like some one love Kratos and praise him as a god of war)  that I will get sin or not?

thank you for your answer hope allah will reward you and sorry if my english is not good hope you understand :)

Comment: I would say call it lord of war. Replace God with Lord and don't mean God by "Lord". It is the best thing you can do I wouldn't recommend doing anything related to God.

Answer (score 1):

This would be haram.

Joking or using gods or religion for fun is forbidden in Islam. Games would certainly fall under that.

Religion is serious and it cannot be taken lightly.

Allah says:

> And if you ask them, they will surely say, "We were only conversing and playing." Say, "Is it Allah and His verses and His Messenger that you were mocking?"
>
> Make no excuse; you have disbelieved after your belief. If We pardon one faction of you - We will punish another faction because they were criminals. (9:65-66)

It should also be emphasized that Shirk is a huge sin.